# Find the missing angle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image]

The above diagram shows a rectangle and  4 congruent squares. We are supposed to find the missing angle marked in the digram.

My attempt to solve the question:

I constructed some line segments as shown in the picture below.

[image]

Nothing didn't help. And also I've no idea what to construct to solve this problem.

Comment: It's not clear what quantities you know. Maybe some lengths or ratio of lengths?

Comment: I only know that the angles marked as 'a' are equal

Comment: If the size of the big rectangle is $3\times2$ in terms of small square sides, then the angle is $45^\circ$. If there is unique solution, this must be it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Hint: Please notice that $\angle CMD = \angle AMB$. Also $\angle BSQ = \angle CRP$. So, what's the relationship between $MB$ and $MC$, and therefore between $AM$ and $MD$?

Can you finish?

Comment: Thank you very much Math Lover found the answer 45

Comment: Yes that's right!